# Send automatic mail via html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a website to can handle orders for a business.

How do I email the whole final order and also do it automatically and not open a new window to send mail?

The order template for the mail:
Name of the customer: XXX
Phone number: XXX
City where he live: XXX
Address that he live: XXX
Date he want to get the product: XXX
Table with two columns: Name of the product ordered and quantity of the same product

The code should work like this: When someone presses "הוספה לסל" (sorry for the hardness with the Hebrew) the item is added to the cart and when the customer presses "להזמנה" the order is sent to the mail.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sap Patisserie | חנות</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <script src="store.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
                <nav class="main-nav nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html">קצת עלי</a></li>
                        <li><a href="store.html">חנות</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">בית</a>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            <h1 class="sap-name sap-name-large">Sap Patisserie</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">עוגות</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">מארז סינבון</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/cina.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">35₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title" id="koTitle">עוגת שמרים (קינדר / אוראו)</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" id="koImage" src="Images/food/kinder_oreo.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details" id="koDetails">
                        <span class="shop-item-price" id="koPrice">45₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" id="koAdd" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                        <select id="koSelect">
                            <option value="kinder">קינדר</option>
                            <option value="oreo">אוראו</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">טארט דבש מלוח</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/tart_honey.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">80₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">טארט שוקולד ואגוזי לוז</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/tart_peanut.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">90₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">טארט תפוחים</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/tart_apple.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">100₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </br>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">פחזניות</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">פחזניות במילוי קצפת</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/pach_katz.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">55₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">פחזניות במילוי קראמבל במילוי קרם פטיסייר</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/ani.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">55₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">פחזניות במילוי קרם פטיסייר מצופות בקרמל</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/pach_caramel.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">55₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </br>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">עוגיות</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">מיני עוגיות אמסטרדם (18 יחידות)</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/mini_amsterdam.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">30₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">מיני עוגיות שוקולד צ'יפס (18 יחידות)</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/maaraz_chips.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">30₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">עוגיות ריבה (15 יחידות)</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/maaraz_riba.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">35₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">עוגיות אלפחורס (22 יחידות)</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/maaraz_alfa.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">45₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">מארז לבחירה (7 יחידות)</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/ani.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">50₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">מארז עוגיות לבחירה (9 יחידות)</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/maaraz_9.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">60₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">מארז קינדר בוקס</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/food/kinder_box.jpg">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">60₪</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">הוספה לסל</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </br>
    <form action="order.php" method="post">
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">הסל שלי</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">כמות</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">מחיר</span>
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">מוצר</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2" width="50%">
                            <div class="cart-total">
                                <strong class="cart-total-title">סך הכל</strong>
                                <span class="cart-total-price">0₪</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" width="25%">
                            <input type="text" id="inpPhone" size="10" required>
                            :טלפון
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" width="25%">
                            <input type="text" id="inpName" size="10" required>
                            :שם מלא
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" width="25%">
                            <input type="text" id="inpCity" size="10" required>
                            :עיר
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" width="25%">
                            <input type="text" id="inpAddress" size="10" required>
                            :כתובת
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="right">
                            <input type="date" id="inpDate" required>
                            :תאריך אספקה (ניתן להזמין עד יומיים לפני)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="right">
                            </br>
                            אם הוזמנו מארז עוגיות/עוגת שמרים, יווצר עמך קשר בהמשך לגבי בחירת עוגיות/עוגה *
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="submit" name="btnBuy">להזמנה</button>
        </section>
    </form>
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container main-footer-container">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="Images/logo.png" height="150">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sap_patisserie/" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/instagram.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Sap-patisserie-105353121705622" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/facebook_c.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://wa.me/972523390519?text=שלום ספיר, אשמח לשמוע קצת פרטים!"  target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/whatsapp.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div align="right" style="color:#adadad">
                Copyright Ⓒ 2021 Ofek Tzarfati (OTFH). All Right Reserved.
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('תודה רבה שקנית :)')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('הוספת כבר את המוצר הזה לסל')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">הסר</button>
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1" id="quan_final">        
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <span class="cart-item-title" name="title_final">${title}</span>
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
        </div>
        
        `
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('₪', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = total + '₪'
}
```

Comment: Not going to happen with just clientside JavaScript

Comment: So can you help me please with other coding language to script this?

Comment: Given that you have `<form action="order.php" method="post">` the website is clearly using PHP, which means that's what you can use to send the email. There [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php) which might already work without further setup. And you can always use a custom solution like PHP mailer.

Answer (score 2):

Client side JavaScript alone cannot send email. It's highly locked-down in the browser environment to not allow the type of outgoing connections required to deliver email to an email server.

You may be able to use an external service to send email from your server side code (where you use a POST request to send your desired email to a service's API and the service delivers the email on your behalf), but recommending a service like that isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Some might also recommend mailing directly from PHP, which is fine if your host allows you to and you're sending to your friend's one address (if you were sending to external addresses, you would want to use a mail service for better deliverability).

Finally, as NoName mentioned in the comments, the easiest option may be to use a form sending service. This service will let you POST your form directly to their server and notify you of its contents in an email.

Comment: Can you please recommend me for some service?
Or any idea of how doing it without service and use just other coding than JavaScript?

Comment: You can find lots of great services by googling "send mail via api", but actually getting your setup to work would be the realm of a multi-page tutorial.

Comment: @OfekTzarfati Google `php mail()` or `php pear mail package`

Comment: There are also tons of form sending services, you can search for something like `send the form as email service`. For example, we personally use Formspree.io for our landing pages.